# onBeforeUnload not working correctly for Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, microsoft-edge, onbeforeunload

I've been using this code for some time and it worked fine until yesterday:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "¡Atención! Si continúas no podrás volver atrás y podrías perder datos. Revisa todos los campos y termina el trabajo antes de moverte de esta página. ¿Seguro que quieres continuar?";
}
```

The problem now is that Chrome shows this:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

But Edge shows it the right way:

[image: Edge screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

***Note:*** Language is not the problem because I've tried with both English and Spanish.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. Google has decided to do what Mozilla did and not allow you to show a custom message anymore. It [took effect in Chrome 51](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5349061406228480).

You still need to return something to trigger the built-in dialog, but you're no longer allowed to determine what that dialog says.

[Here's the BugZilla entry](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292) where Mozilla decided to do it in Firefox.

[Here's the Chrome issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587940) where Google decided to do it in Chrome.

*(The new Chrome 51 behavior was [reported as a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=618611&can=1&q=onbeforeunload&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified), but naturally it was closed within hours as it's by design.)

Comment: +1. When I initially tried to run OP's code, it worked as expected in [this example](http://jsbin.com/sozeco/edit?js,output), however after updating to 51.0.2704.84, it now returns the expected message.