# how to store time spent on a page and dynamically show them using php

Tags: php

I want to develop a page which stores the total time consumed in a page in a database and when I again login to the same page the time start counting after the old time which I had stored in the database.Since I am new to php I developed some code which is not working at all please help!

```
<?php
$s=0;
$m=0;
$h=0;
while(true)
{
    if($s==60)
    {
    $s=0;
        if($m==60)
        {
            $m=0;
            $h++;
        }
        else
        {
            $m++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $s++;
    }
    sleep(1);
    echo $h." ".$m." ".$s." ";

}
?>
```

This is what I tried please help!

Comment: It's not working as it's a server side code which won't determine if you've finished browsing. You need a combination of Client side and server side code.

Comment: PHP runs server side so you won't be able to get that information in PHP. You'll need ajax calls from javascript. One when the page loads and another when the page closes. A php script would simply catch the token and times and log it to the database.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have much idea about ajax can you please help?

Comment: Use Google analytics. It will give you more than just the time. It's much easier to implement GA than to reinvent the wheel (and the carriage for that matter)

Comment: its better to use a heart beat, on the page set an interval that is say `10s` then store start time and end time, then if its longer the `interval + fudge` make a new record.  fudge is just a few seconds to account for network latency,  it wont be `100%` accurate, but there is not an event server-side that tells you a page is closed.  If it's less then just update the end time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a setup like this:

1. Create a JavaScript code that calls a PHP page every x seconds to increase a counter stored in the database
2. Create the PHP file that increases the counter in the database for a specific page
3. Include the Javascript code on every page you are interested in counting the time spent by a user

The `Javascript` part is something like:

```
<!-- let's say this is a sample page 'page_id.html' -->
<html>
<head>
   <!-- include JQuery -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- your page goes here-->
   <!-- then at the END -->
   <script>
   // set the user ID
   var USER_ID = "user_1";
   // set the id of the page in the database
   var PAGE_ID = "page_id.html";
   // set the timer accuracy - ex. 5 seconds
   var TIMER_ACCURACY = 5000;
   // create the counter function
   (function(UI, PID, TA){
      // cal the PHP file every x seconds
      var I = setInterval(function(){
        // use AJAX so the page doesn't need to reload
        $.ajax({
          method:"post",
          url:"ajax.php", // this is the link to the PHP file
          data:{call:"counter", user_id: UI, page_id:PID}
        })
        .fail() // put some code here if server is unreachable
        .done(); // put some code here to check server response
      }, TA);
   })(USER_ID, PAGE_ID, TIMER_ACCURACY);
   </script>
</body>
```

The `PHP` part:

```
<?php
// page "ajax.php"
// check $_POST data -> see if there is a call for "counter"
if (isset($_POST["call"]) && $_POST["call"] == "counter" && isset($_POST["user_id"]) && isset($_POST["page_id"])) {
    // if there is, retrieve user_id & page_id
    // filter $_POST data before using it into database
    // ex. user only Alphanumeric chars and . _ -
    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_.-]/", "", $_POST["user_id"]);
    $page_id = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_.-]/", "", $_POST["page_id"]);
    // create an appropriate SQL query to UPDATE the counter for the HTML page with the user ID = $user_id page ID = $page_id
    $sql = "UPDATE.... WHERE ....";
    // run the query, update the counter
    // if all ok
    echo "1";
    exit;
}
// if something goes wrong
echo "0";
exit;
?>
```

To include the Javascript part on every page, you should setup a template for rendering the HTML page that includes the script and that echoes the correct PAGE_ID like:

```
<?php
$user_id = "user_id"; // user identifier in the database
$page_id = "page_id.html"; // page identifier in the database
?>
<html>
...
<script>
// set the id of the page in the database
var USER_ID = "<?php echo $user_id.html; ?>";
var PAGE_ID = "<?php echo $page_id.html; ?>";
...
```

Comment: If he needs to know the time spent on a page why you would send a request every X times ? I think if you sent the request only as the page is closing like @Aunt Jamaima said, it will be enough and more resource saving

Comment: But how would you know when the page closes? You could use javascript for "onbeforeunload" event, but in some browsers (Chrome) it doesn't let you execute a custom code.

Comment: I looked it up. I think all major browsers includes Chrome support the event (reference : ([https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)))

Comment: But try it in Chrome. You will see that there are restrictions. There is a default message displayed, and no custom functions are allowed. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37726387/4902724

Comment: You are right, thanks for the information. Sorry for the late response I just tested an arbitrary code in the event handler and it didn't executed as you said.